# Move js script to external file

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following code in a div to move the div when clicking on he move button:

```
    <input id="move1" class="smallButtonidle" type="button" value="M" style="top: 0px; left: 0px; float: left;"  />
<script type="text/javascript">
var isDown1 = false;
document.getElementById('move1').addEventListener('mousedown', function(e1)
 {
    isDown1 = true;
    offset = [document.getElementById('jsmolwindow1').offsetLeft - e1.clientX,
        document.getElementById('jsmolwindow1').offsetTop - e1.clientY];
}, true);
window.addEventListener('mouseup', function() {
    isDown1 = false;
}, true);
window.addEventListener('mousemove', function(event) {
    if (isDown1) {
       mousePosition = {
          x : event.clientX,
         y : event.clientY
   };
        document.getElementById('jsmolwindow1').style.left = (mousePosition.x + offset[0]) + 'px';
        document.getElementById('jsmolwindow1').style.top  = (mousePosition.y + offset[1]) + 'px';
    }
}, true);
</script>
```

I would like to move this js script to an external file to clarify my html

I modify my html code the following way :

```
 <input id="move1" class="smallButtonidle" type="button" value="M" style="top: 0px; left: 0px; float: left;"  onclick="move1js()"/>
```

And put in an include js external file:

```
function move1js()
{
var isDown1 = false;
document.getElementById('move1').addEventListener('mousedown', function(e1)
 {
    isDown1 = true;
    offset = [document.getElementById('jsmolwindow1').offsetLeft - e1.clientX,
        document.getElementById('jsmolwindow1').offsetTop - e1.clientY];
}, true);
window.addEventListener('mouseup', function() {
    isDown1 = false;
}, true);
window.addEventListener('mousemove', function(event) {
    if (isDown1) {
       mousePosition = {
          x : event.clientX,
         y : event.clientY
   };
        document.getElementById('jsmolwindow1').style.left = (mousePosition.x + offset[0]) + 'px';
        document.getElementById('jsmolwindow1').style.top  = (mousePosition.y + offset[1]) + 'px';
    }
}, true);
}
```

Doing so my move button stop working. I don't understand why.

Any ideas?

Comment: Your internal JS in not working either..

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Steps for your solution are:

1. Create a javascript file (a file with extension `.js`). Lets
   suppose the file is `moveDiv.js`
2. Move all the javascript code into this newly created file **as it is
   except** `<script>` & `</script>` tags.
3. Give reference to this file in your HTML file as

   `<script src="moveDiv.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`

This should start moving your button again.

Comment: A few years old, but the `src="moveDiv.js"` may need to include a relative path definition, such as `src="~/Scripts/moveDiv.js"` if the script is in the scripts folder, or `src="~/moveDiv.js"` if the script is in the root folder.

Comment: What if the original code in the script part contains small parts of `php`?