# Moving javascript file to external reference in Node.JS called HTML

Tags: javascript, node.js, reference

I have some javascript ajax code in my html page that I host on a Node.JS server.

I would like to move it to a specific side .js file to be able to debug but can't figure out how. The solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32942778/move-js-script-to-external-file) doesn't work.

It seems due to scope but not sure how to solve it.

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#mainTable').DataTable( {
        "ajax": "jsonData",
        "columns": [
            { "data": "level" },
            { "data": "value" },
            { "data": "description" }
        ]
    } );
  } );
</script>
```

**EDIT**

Reason for doing so:

1. Wishing to have a clean split bet. script and html
2. Being able to debug the scripting part (seems not possible in Visual Studio Code for the part that is in the html file)
3. Solve some import issue that doesn't seem to work in the html script section

For #3, see below as an example, the require doesn't work although path is correct:

```
<script>
    window.onload = function() {
    var a = document.getElementById("books");
    a.onclick = function() {
        var utils = require('./../controllers/utils.js');
        var filteredData = utils.filterJsonData(table, "HighLevel");
    }
</script>
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

In your html page add the following.

```
<script src="./somename.js"></script>
<script src="./../controllers/utils.js"></script>
```

In your somename.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#mainTable').DataTable({
      "ajax": "jsonData",
      "columns": [
        { "data": "level" },
        { "data": "value" },
        { "data": "description" }
      ]
  });
  $('a#books').click(function(){
    //Where is table coming from?
    var filteredData = utils.filterJsonData(table, 'HighLevel');
  });
});
```

As for being easier to debug between a separate js vs in a single html page, it should not matter. It should be the same effort to debug in the browser.

require works only in nodejs which can be used in server side js code. Are you using some library that provides require in browsers?

Comment: thanks a lot! I am trying to do so, however seems the ./somename.js is never called although the path is fine (just did a simple test in the somename.js file: $("#testTitle").text("called");... but not updating the h4 tag in my html). As for your question, that html page is actually served by Node.JS: res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname + '/views/index.html'));

Comment: Is somename.js in the same location as the html page? Also, open the browser debugger and refresh the page. Check if the js file is being requested. I am assuming it is a 404 adjust the url till the file is loaded

Comment: you're right the issues is a 404. Though it is in the same location. But given the the html file is served through nodejs, the location might be based on that one. I'm checking

Answer (score 0):

Move the code that is currently inside of your `script` tag to a separate file, say `side.js`:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#mainTable').DataTable( {
        "ajax": "jsonData",
        "columns": [
            { "data": "level" },
            { "data": "value" },
            { "data": "description" }
        ]
    } );
  } );
```

Change the script tag to be

```
<script source="./side.js"></script>
```

It looks from some of your other code (`require...`) that you are attempting to execute Node.js inside of the HTML. Node.js is executed on the *server* side; all of the Javascript in the HTML will be executed on the client-side (browser).

---

ETA: now that you've updated with the code, I see that, yes, you are attempting to use Node.js inside of the HTML. It won't work - you can't `require` inside of the user's browser.