# Best practices for large javascript file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, javascript-objects

I am creating a web page using html,css and js and I am not following any framework so I have only page (that was the requirement). So I have lot of javascript in my page and I want to move my javascript to another script file. So I have two quesions:
1) What's the best way to do that?
2) Is there any way to call my functions as a property like we can do with node_modules.

```
var printMsg = require('printModule');
printMsg.print();
```

or in jquery ($.whatever())

Comment: You might look into Webpack, which allows for strong code organization: https://medium.com/the-node-js-collection/modern-javascript-explained-for-dinosaurs-f695e9747b70

Comment: 1. [Move js script to external file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32942778/move-js-script-to-external-file)

2. [How do I include a JavaScript file in another JavaScript file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/950087/how-do-i-include-a-javascript-file-in-another-javascript-file)

Answer (score 1):

1. The currently best way to organize your project is through using Webpack. It's allow you to module your js code easily and they a have plugins for almost everything. Take a look at their [guide](https://webpack.js.org/guides/getting-started/) as knowing webpack will make your life easier. Using their guide, It might take you 5-6 hours depend on your dedication.
2. That's  ES6 and knowing webpack will solve like 99% of your problems.

[Here](https://github.com/GTHell/simple-webpack-template)'s my webpack-simple-template. You can take a look at how I set thing up.

Comment: +1 for webpack. I moved away from grunt and gulp ever since I tried webpack. Popular framework such as Angular-cli adopted it.